# Read MS Word file page by page with header and footer using OpenXml and iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net, itext, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm new in `OpenXml` and recently started development using `OpenXml` with `ASP.Net(C#/Vb)`.

I want to read MS Word file page by page with header and footer using `OpenXml` and then write those pages to `pdf` file using `iTextSharp`.

Code for Reference:

```
Dim fileName As String = "D:\With_Header.docx"
Dim body As Body
Dim contentOfFile As String = String.Empty

Dim pdfDoc As New iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30)
Dim pdfWriter As PdfWriter = pdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, fs)

Using strm As Stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open)
    Using doc As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(strm, False)
        body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body
        contentOfFile = body.InnerText

        pdfDoc.Add(New iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(contentOfFile))
        pdfDoc.Close()
        pdfWriter.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Show what you have done so far.

Comment: First I created reference/object of WordProcessingDocument and then Open MS Word file through Stream in ReadOnly mode.
Also read content of file by MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InnerText which return content of all pages.
But I want to read file page by page.

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: Does this code not work? Do you get an exception? I'm not sure what your specific question is.

Comment: It's not possible to read Word Open XML "page by page" - that's not how Word was designed. Word is a word-processor and bases on text flow, it's not a page layout software. The Word application lays pages out dynamically when they're opened in the UI, based on the current configuration's screen and print drivers. So the layout can be different from machine to machine.